# CORS set but not effecting the request

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, gsutil

I am trying to create a head request on a link generated using Firebase Functions using `getSignedURL` method.

I want to check if the URL is still alive and is not expired for that I am

And for cors I used gsutils from cloud shell on cloud.google.com and setup the cors:

```
gsutil cors set cors.json gs://mybucket.appspot.com
Setting CORS on gs://mybucket.appspot.com/...
di@cloudshell:~ (ecutter-web)$ gsutil cors get gs://mybucket.appspot.com
[{"maxAgeSeconds": 300, "method": ["HEAD"], "origin": ["https://myapp.web.app"],         
"responseHeader": ["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"]}]
```

but when I make a head request to that URL it shows error :

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://storage.googleapis.com/myapp.appspot.com/public/myfile.doc?GoogleAccessId=firebase-adminsdk-7u2d7%40myapp.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1603783901&Signature=... (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

this is the cors.json:

```
[
    {
      "origin": ["https://myapp.web.app"],
      "method": ["HEAD"],
      "responseHeader": ["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"],
      "maxAgeSeconds": 300
    }
]
```

original appname is replaced with `myapp`.

and function to check the validity :

```
function loadhandle() {
        console.log('logging');
        console.log(this.responseText);
    }
    function checkUrl(s) {
        console.log('creating request');
        var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xml.addEventListener("load", loadhandle, false);
        xml.open("HEAD", s);
        xml.send();
    }
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I was setting the `CORS` at afternoon so my connection was not that fast and i found that cloud shell was struggling to get up and running.

So

You can set `CORS` on `getSignedUrl` using `gsutils` and i used `Cloud shell` from `console.cloud.google.com` to avoid any installation.

in cloud shell first check for if any `CORS` configuration is present by running command:

```
 gsutil cors get gs://yourstoragebucketname
```

then upload your `CORS` file using upload file menu item. in my case file name was `cors.json`

```
 gsutil cors set cors.json gs://yourstoragebucketname
```

Verify if `CORS` is set correctly by calling again

```
 gsutil cors get gs://yourstoragebucketname
```

Your `cors.json` should look like this:

```
[
   {
      "origin":[
         "https://myapp.web.app",
         "http://localhost:5000"
      ],
      "method":[
         "HEAD"
      ],
      "responseHeader":[
         "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
      ],
      "maxAgeSeconds":300
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

From Google documentation:

The authenticated browser download endpoint `storage.cloud.google.com` does not allow CORS requests. Note that the Cloud Console provides this endpoint for each object's public URL link.

You can use either of the following XML API request URLs to obtain a response from Cloud Storage that contains the CORS headers:

```
storage.googleapis.com/BUCKET_NAME
```

or

```
BUCKET_NAME.storage.googleapis.com
```

Looking at the error you encountered:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at 
https://storage.googleapis.com/...(Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
```

[Reference](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin#server-side-support)

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Hey @tzovourn , I actually didn't understood what you really want to say ? are saying to `storage.googleapi` as host while making request ? if yes then `getSignedUrl` by default returns link like you said `storage.googleapis.com/myBucket/pathtofile and so on` However it is now i think working so it seems like that it takes some time to update in the bucket.

Comment: The weird thing is that CORS only works if the status code is 200 in my case that was all i needed but in other cases where we need/want to handle all those situations then i don't know maybe a new stackoverflow question ?

Comment: Please open a new StackOverflow question stating all the details for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this help but if I use your code with GET method instead of HEAD to check and it works.

I also used useEffect, and dont you fetch because CORS only affect to XMLrequest.

Finally, I configed using Anaconda Prompt with a command like this:

> gsutil cors set C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/cors_config.json gs://BUCKET_NAME